# How to read base64 xml format data and how to get value in java

Tags: java

In my table i'm maintains one xml column in that column data is in base64 xml format,so now i got this column with query.

Now how to read xml format data.

here my code:

```
public Object readingSqlResultedRecord(ResultSet result){

try {
Query q="select xml from empdata";
String xml = result.getString(1);
System.out.println("----xml----"+xml);
}catch (SQLException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

and my column is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<event id="370e7324-3-85ec-63dac16aacb6">
<properties>
<property enc="BASE64" name="CHEF:description-html" value="ZmhfrtRo"/>
<property enc="BASE64" name="DAV:name" value="Q2FsZWmnmewqzRlYXI="/>
</properties>
</event>
```

How to read **XML** and how to get name value with string format.

Answer (score 1):

this code will help you get the id attribute of event. It will work the same way for other nodes / attributes. A good **[start tutorial](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/org.w3c.dom.NodeList):**

```
File fXmlFile = new File("path_to_your_xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("event");
String id = nList.getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue();
```

and then the decoding is supported in Java 8 ( java.util.Base64, java.util.Base64.Encoder and java.util.Base64.Decoder ). so all you need to do is:

```
byte[] decode= Base64.getDecoder().decode(id);
```

Comment: i want **<property enc="BASE64" name="DAV:name" value="Q2FsZWmnmewqzRlYXI="/>** value only

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, your column contains a Base64 value. 
When you do:

```
String xml = result.getString(1);
```

Variable xml has a [Base64 value](https://www.base64decode.org/). So, first you should decode xml variable value.You should use this snippet:

```
String decodeXmlValue = BaseEncoding.base64().decode(xml)
```

If `decodeXmlValue` contains a XML string, you should unmarshaller the XML value, take a look to [Mashaller java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html).

Base64 library can be included in your project from maven using this [dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.2). If you are not using maven in your project, you will be able to download the jar from [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.2/commons-codec-1.2.jar) and include in your project.

Comment: You don't need guava for this anymore or a 3rd party lib. Base64 is supported in Java 8

Comment: @Sri are you using Java 8?

Comment: @kiuby_88 in my PC have jdk1.6.0 and jre1.6.0